# I get a error message whenever I try and start my discord bot it says ReferenceError: client is not defined, and my bot wont start because of that

Tags: javascript, discord, client, bots

I have

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

```
client.commands.set(command.name, command);
```

}

cleint.once('ready', () => {
console.log('KindnessBot is online!');
cleint.user.setActivity('Use !help for a list of commands, made by Keaton8legs', { type: 'WATCHING' }).catch(console.error);
});

cleint.on('message', message =>{
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === 'ping'){
    client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
```

and i also have

module.export = {
name: 'ping',
description: "this is a ping command!",
execute(message, args){
message.channel.send('pong!');
}
}

Comment: Please take the time needed to learn how to format your question properly. That will make it more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`client` isn't defined, you need to define it as an instance of Discord.Client, like:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Comment: const Discord = require('discord.js');

const cleint = new Discord.Client();

Comment: It looks like you mispelled `client` as `cleint`

Answer (score 0):

Your haven haven't defined client

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();
```